# Use list element to build new path

Tags: arcpy, list, windowserror

I'm currently trying to build two lists containing folder names, in order to use their elements for geoprocessing tools later on. However I struggle with creating the lists. I'm using ArcGIS 10.3 (Python 2.7).

**What I need:**

`C:\test` contains multiple subfolders that I would like to put in the first list, i.e. `C:\test\test1`, `C:\test\test2`, etc. The first set of subfolders contains another set, i.e. `C:\test\test1\xy1`, `C:\test\test1\xy2` etc. What I need is a list with the names, not the paths, to each of the first level subfolders as in `firstlevelList = [test1, test2, test3]` and `secondlevelList = [xy1, xy2, xy3]`. I then want to use the `arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management` function to process data in each of the secondlevelList separetely (sort of according to [this question](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/76345)).

**What I've tried:**

```
import arcpy, os

workspace = r"C:\test"
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
arcpy.env.scratchworkspace = workspace
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


firstlevelList = []
firstlevelList.append(os.listdir(workspace))
## up to here, everything works very well, the list contains all the available subfolders in my workspace.

secondlevelList = []
for element in firstlevelList:
    newPath = """{0}\{1}""".format(workspace, element)
    secondlevelList.append(os.listdir(newPath))

## This creates the following error:
##Runtime error
##Traceback (most recent call last):
##  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
##WindowsError: [Error 3] Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden: "C:\\Users\\sutter\\Desktop\\GIS_temp\\test\\['test1', 'test2', 'test3']/*.*"
```

I understand that apparently I cannot use a list element to create a new path? 
I then also tried to following, which worked for one element of the fistlevelList() but not for all of them... :

```
secondlevelList = []
i = 0
for element in firstlevelList:
     newPath = """{0}\{1}""".format(workspace, element[i])
     secondlevelList.append(os.listdir(newPath))
     i += 1
```

Am I using the `os.listdir` function the wrong way? My knowledge about the `os.path` / `os.walk` functions is rather limited but I guess they could also help? Would I be better off using the `arcpy.ListFiles()` function?

**The aim of the script:**
Finally I would like to create a mosaic for all rasters in the secondlevelList separately. Example: folder `C:\test\test1\xy1` contains 3 rasters. They need to be mosaiced. Then the following folder needs to be processed `C:\test\test1\xy2` etc. I wrote this code for doing this:

```
for tile in firstlevelList:
    for run in secondlevelList:
        zeitschrittRaster = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "TIF")
        arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(zeitschrittRaster, Sammelordner, """{0}.tif""".format(run), "", "32_BIT_FLOAT", 10, 1, "MAXIMUM", "FIRST")
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need only the folder names instead of full paths? The Mosaic to New Raster accepts the full paths to the datasets.

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov: thanks for your comment. You are right - then my sencondlevelList could also contain paths. I'll quickly edit my question and add the code for the mosaic to new raster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are dedicated list functions in arcpy and I would use them rather than the python `os.listdir` function:

```
import arcpy, os

workspace = r"C:\test"
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
arcpy.env.scratchworkspace = workspace
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

firstlevelList = arcpy.ListWorkspaces(workspace_type = "Folder")

for element in firstlevelList:
    arcpy.env.workspace = element
    secondlevelList = arcpy.ListFiles()
    for file in secondlevelList:
        # do something
```

`file` represents the file itself even though if you print it you will only get its name. You can input it to a tool without having to recreate the full path to the file. Nevertheless if you want to do this for some reason, add this line under the last `for` block:

```
path_to_file = os.path.join(ws, file)
```

Depending on the type of the files (rasters?) and what you want to do with them, another list function might be more approriate:

- [arcpy.ListRasters()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listrasters.htm)
- [arcpy.ListDatasets()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listdatasets.htm)
- [arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfeatureclasses.htm)
- ...

See also the help page for [arcpy.ListWorkspaces()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listworkspaces.htm) and [arcpy.ListFiles()](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/listfiles.htm).

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot! I easily managed to put the list together like this by slightly modifing your code.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you: [Using Python to execute merge of rasters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/185696/using-python-to-execute-merge-of-rasters-linux/193865#193865)

I used os.path.join and os.walk ([os path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html))